# StackExchange widget links to 404

Tags: support, specific-question

I commented on a question some days ago.

Recently the StackExchange widget showed a red icon, clicking it showed

> comment on
>
> grep results in putty
> (windows 7) terminal change depending
> on width of terminal
>
> i guarantee that
> the lines are different, not just

When I click on this I am taken to a SuperUser "page not found" page.

Has the Q been moved? If so, why is stack exchange directing me to the wrong place?

Comment: More likely the question was deleted for some reason, but we need a moderator or someone with 10k rep to check the location for you to see if that is the case - posting the link here would probably be helpful for them.

Comment: What's the link to the question ?

Comment: Also, check out [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68796/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-sometimes-links-to-the-wrong-page) post on Meta.SO - it looks like this is a similar problem (that is now potentially fixed).

Comment: I didn't keep a note of the link. If you view the pop-down list, the items are not shown the next time you open it. So I don't know how to retrieve the link.

Comment: I found the link, it had just been moved down by newer items appearing at the top. The link in the stackexchange drop-down window is http://superuser.com/questions/203911/grep-results-in-putty-windows-7-terminal-change-depending-on-width-of-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been deleted by the owner of the question.

Comment: Thanks. I can't help feeling that there must be a better way to handle this than having the stackexchange dropdown widget show me a broken link.

Comment: It's not a broken link per-se.. since 10k+ rep users can view the link, but yeah perhaps something like a (deleted) at the end of the link would be useful